# Redis client - on('ready') event

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using the Redis NPM library for Node.js - I can listen for the connection 'ready' event like so

```
var client = require('redis').createClient();

client.on('ready', function () {
    client.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
        if (err) {
            log.error(err);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                createLocalDataMap(keys[i]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

however, how can I query Redis to see if it's ready instead of listening for an event that will probably fire before I am ready to handle it?

I suppose I could abandon the ready event and just do a query and then wait for a response, but is there a better, safer and more sophisticated way?

In other words, in all likelihood I will have to write a function like this:

```
var isReady = false;

client.on('ready', function(){

      isReady = true;
});

function doSomethingMuchLater(){

if(isReady){

     //query redis as normal
}
else {

   client.on('ready', function(){
   isReady = true;
     //now I do what I wanted to do
   });

}
}
```

this does not seem right at all, there must be a better way

Comment: you dont have to worry about on ready if it really is doSomethingMuchLater. It will be connected by then.

Comment: yeah but (a) I hate race conditions with a passion (b) what if the connection failed ----> therefore I should check the state

Comment: If it fails do something on('error'). Beats checkin on ready for every single connection

Comment: I agree that solves (b) but I want a more elegant solution in order to solve (a)

Comment: Did you see my answer from 2 days ago?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The node-redis client automatically queues any commands you send before the connection is ready.  Once it connects, those commands all get sent just before .on('ready') fires.  As such, you really don't need to use .on('ready'). If you send commands too early, they'll still go through as expected, and if your connection fails entirely, they'll never be sent.

Comment: This isn't true if enable_offline_queue is false(defaults to true). There are many situations where this option could be disabled, in which case your answer is incorrect. At that point what would you do?

Comment: @RobertMennell - I know it's 5 years later, but to answer your question - if you don't want the offline queue, then wait for the `ready` event to fire. You will need to keep your own state like the OP suggested (re: `isReady`) and you will need to listen for `error` and `end` events to update your internal state. You could wrap all this up in an async function (promise) which resolves or rejects accordingly. That's a lot of boilerplate, but that's what you'd have to do if you disable the offline queue.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the commands are queued, I got some nasty logging errors because I sending commands while the DB was not fully loaded. The `connect` event did not suffice.

From the docs:

> [options.enableReadyCheck]    boolean
>
> When a connection is established to the Redis server, the server might still be loading the database from disk. While loading, the server not respond to any commands. To work around this, when this option is true, ioredis will check the status of the Redis server, and when the Redis server is able to process commands, a ready event will be emitted.

So this is the only way I could make it reliably work is by using the `ioredis` library:

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';

class RedisClient {
  private static instance: Redis.Redis | undefined;
  private redisUrl: string;
  private options?: Redis.RedisOptions;

  private constructor(
    redisUrl?: string,
    options?: Redis.RedisOptions,
  ) {
    this.redisUrl = redisUrl || `redis://${REDIS.HOST}:${REDIS.PORT}`;
    this.options = options;
  }

  static async init(
    redisUrl?: string,
    options?: Redis.RedisOptions,
  ): Promise<RedisClient | undefined> {
    try {
      RedisClient.instance = new Redis(RedisClient.redisUrl, {
        ...options,
        enableReadyCheck: true,
      });
      const onReady = (): Promise<boolean> => new Promise((resolve) => {
        (RedisClient.instance as Redis.Redis).on('ready', () => {
          resolve(true);
          infoLogger.info('Redis server online...');
        });
      });
      await onReady();
      return new RedisClient(redisUrl, {
        ...options,
        enableReadyCheck: true
      });
    } catch (err) {
      new ServerError({
        message: 'Redis client init error.',
        internalCode: ErrorCodes.cacheInitError,
        internal: true,
      }).log();

      if (RedisClient.instance) RedisClient.instance.quit();
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  async get(key: string): Promise<someType> {
    ...
  }

  async set<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(key: string, value: Stringified<T> | string): Promise<void> {
    ...
  }

  async del(key: string): Promise<void> {
    ...
  }

  async flush(): Promise<void> {
    ...
  }
}
```

```
import RedisClient from 'somewhere';

const redis = await RedisClient.init();
```